# Return MVC final current path in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, url

Right now I'm using...

```
window.location.pathname != "/x_Controller/x_View"
```

Is there any way to get just the "x_View"? Thanks.

Comment: So to restate, you want to determine the Action name from Javascript?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense because if right now you are using `window.location.pathname != "/x_Controller/x_View"` and you wanted to get only the `x_View` you would write `window.location.pathname != "/x_View"`. So obviously right now you are not using anything like this. So the question is: what is your question?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Yes, exactly. Thanks. Sorry for the brain fart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a substring of the `window.location.pathname`

```
var pathname= window.location.pathname;
var endURL= pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,pathname.length);
```

**EDIT**

As Galactic suggested this won't get you the action name if it has any route values on the end like `actionName/12`. What you really want to use is

```
var endURL=@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue;
```

That will get you the actual name of the Action instead of just the stuff after the last '/'

Comment: As long as the Action name is actually the last thing in the URL.  However, one of the default MVC routes is {controller}/{action}/{id}, which would return the id value instead.

Comment: True. I didn't read the comments to see exactly what it was for.

Comment: It works, but is there any way to have it in an outside .js file? Or does it have to be inline?